# Boolean condition is reading True, but the while loop still isn't breaking

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason the while loop is not breaking when the condition is met. The while loop should be checking for a players input to fill up a tic tac toe board until the variable "win" reads True.

Once the board reflects one of the winning conditions of tic tac toe, it assigns the variable "win" to True, and in turn should break out of the loop.

For some reason the loop isn't breaking, but the variable "win" is still reading True.

**Can someone explain why the loop isn't breaking?** I have tried rewriting the condition for the while loop to read "while win == False", but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue either.

I have included some of the functions I am using, and explained some of the simpler ones with a comment next to it.

I am using repl.it to do all of this online and not on a program on my local machine, so I think this may be part of the issue as well.

```
import os
board = ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]

def determine_win(marker):
    # Winning Patterns:
    # (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (3,6,9), (3,5,7), (1,5,9)   

    if board[1]== board[2]==board[3]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[4]== board[5]==board[6]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[7]== board[8]==board[9]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[1]== board[4]==board[7]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[2]== board[5]==board[8]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[3]== board[6]==board[9]==marker:
        return True    
    elif board[3]== board[5]==board[7]==marker:
        return True 
    elif board[1]== board[5]==board[9]==marker:
        return True       
    else:
        return False

player1 = xo() # A Function that takes user input either "X" or O"
if player1 == "X":
    player2 = "O"
else:
    player2 = "X"

win = False
while not win:
    display_board(board) # display_baord(board) takes the list "board" and uses it as input to display the tic tac toe board to the screen. 
    print("\nPlayer 1")
    board[player_turn()] = player1

    win = determine_win(player1)
    print(win) # used to verify if win is changing
    input()    # used to pause the screen for troubleshooting

    display_board(board)
    print("\nPlayer 2")
    board[player_turn()] = player2

    win = determine_win(player2)
    print(win) # used to verify if win is changing
    input()    # used to pause the screen for troubleshooting

print("Win Declared")
```

Comment: A `while` loop only checks the condition once per loop.  If player1's move wins the game, you go ahead and prompt for player2's move; you'd need to add a conditional `break` in the middle of the loop to handle that possibility.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for the info. I guess I didn't fully understand how the while loop checked for it's condition.

Comment: Think about it this way.  At the end of the `while` block the interpreter jumps all the way back up to the `while not win:` line, at which point `win` will be re-evaluated.  So if by the end of your block your `win` is still `False` because of `player2`, it will not escape.

Comment: @Idlehands Thank you for that explanation. That helped clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment said, the reason is because `while` only check the condition of `win` when you finish the whole iteration of the loop. I would prefer the following way to make the code neater:

```
# win = False <-- you don't need this now
while True:
    display_board(board) # display_baord(board) takes the list "board" and uses it as input to display the tic tac toe board to the screen. 
    print("\nPlayer 1")
    board[player_turn()] = player1

    if determine_win(player1):
        print("Player 1 won")
        break # break out of the loop

    display_board(board)
    print("\nPlayer 2")
    board[player_turn()] = player2

    if determine_win(player2):
        print("Player 2 won")
        break # break out of the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not determine_win(player1):
  display_board(board)
  print("\nPlayer 2")
  board[player_turn()] = player2

  win = determine_win(player2)
  # player 2 wins
else:
  # player 1 wins
  win = True
```

use something like this. It is same as @jasonharper and @Idlehands answered